# QGIS test rules with python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

In QGIS 2.14 one can check if a rule gives results:

[image]

Is it possible to do this programmatically with python console? I would look for a way to iterate over all layers and there rules (nested rules!) and print those (layer_name:rule_name) which do not have results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this answer can fully solve your question.

Run this code snippet in the QGIS Python Console:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values(): # Iterate layers
    if type(layer) == QgsVectorLayer and layer.hasGeometryType():
        r = layer.rendererV2()
        if r.type() == 'RuleRenderer':
            for rule in r.rootRule().children(): # Iterate rules
                if rule.filter(): # Filter out empty rules
                    request = QgsFeatureRequest( rule.filter() )
                    count = len( [f for f in layer.getFeatures( request )] )
                    print layer.name() + ' : ' + rule.label() + ' : ' + rule.filterExpression() + ' : ' + str(count)
```

The first `for` loop iterates layers, the second one iterates layer rules. First `if` clause ensures we use vector layers, the second one ensures we only use vector layers with a rule based style, and the last one filters out empty rules.

The result is a list with layer names, rule labels, rule expressions, and the corresponding count, like this:

```
my_point_layer : My Rule :  "my_code" = '1': 6
my_point_layer : My 2nd Rule :  "my_code" IS NULL : 0
my_polygon_layer : My Polygon Rule :  "area" > 100 : 2
my_polygon_layer : My 2nd Polygon Rule :  "area <= 100 : 28
```

You could then use the `count` variable to filter only those with 0 features, which was your original purpose.

Hope this solves your question.

Comment: Hey Germán this looks to good to be true! Unfortuantely I´m getting an error: `http://hastebin.com/akuvilizaq.py`. Do you know what´s going wrong here?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I didn't test the original code with empty rules (those with no filter), but I've now updated the answer to take them into account. If you face any other problem, just tell me, we're approaching the solution.

Comment: WHOOO WHOOO. GENIOUS! This works just great! Many many thanks!

Comment: Great! Glad to have helped you somehow.

Comment: Just another Idea. Would it work to output the results from QGIS as csv?

Comment: Sure, you just need to write into the file instead of printing to the console. You can have a look at the section Writing CSV Files at http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/systems-programming/using-the-csv-module-in-python/

Comment: Thanks Germán, this seems exactly what I´m looking for. Unfortunately when trying it writing the csv I get `AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'close'`. If you have a second could you have a look if you see my mistake? `http://hastebin.com/dizofakufi.py`

Comment: The error you get is because you're using f for the file and in my code snippet I use it for a feature.
Try this instead:  http://hastebin.com/ulovobakin.pas

Comment: Germán this is pure magic! It´s working. Now it´s clear I have to learn more python! thanks you really a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. That's true! Python is nowadays a must. If you're interested in PyQGIS tips, and you happen to use Twitter, you can follow us at @GeoTux2.

Comment: Germán, a really last last last question. Do you know if it´s possible to get max and minscaledenom of a rule through rendererV2 as well?

Comment: The answer to that question is in the [API docs](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsRuleBasedRendererV2_1_1Rule.html). There you can find a list of supported methods and properties of the class you've mentioned. So, yes, you find there scaleMaxDenom and scaleMaxDenom.

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple selection:

```
for layer in layers:
    expression = QgsExpression("your expression goes here")
    features = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expression))
    number_of_features = sum(1 for _ in features) # you should count this in that way beacuse this object is an iterator
    print "Number of features found: " + str(number_of_features)
```

**Edit:**

If you have many rules (the same set of rules for each layer) add another iteration:

```
for layer in layers:
    for rule in rules: # assumed that rules = ["rule 1", "rule 2", ...]
        expression = QgsExpression("your expression goes here")
        features = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expression))
        number_of_features = sum(1 for _ in features)
        if not number_of_features:
            print rule
```

If you have many rules different for each layer, maybe organise them in a dictionary:

```
rules = {"layer1": ["rule 1", "rule 2"], "layer2": ["rule 3", "rule 4"]}

for layer in layers:
    r = rules[layer.name()]
    for rule in r: 
        expression = QgsExpression("your expression goes here")
        features = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expression))
        number_of_features = sum(1 for _ in features)
        if not number_of_features:
            print rule
```

Comment: dmh126 thanks for your reply! Your solution assumes I always have the same expression for all layers/rules, right? But the case if different. I have about 100 Layers each has already ~10 rules and I´d like to now which of these rules are obselete.

Comment: I've edited my post with new solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi dmh126, thanks a lot for your really useful answer. Even if it´s not exactly what I need I accept this as answer. My problem is that I do not know which rules are there. When using a dictionary I have to open every layer look for each expression and copy it. It´s the same time when just pressing the "test" button. That´s why I thought python can help here and iterate over all existing expressions. Anyway as said this is really really useful for me for future projects. thanks!